# Error: Field must not have a selection since type "Boolean!" has no subfields

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js, gql, react-gql

I want to call a GQL function (golang function) on change of checkbox selection. As soon I select the box, I get following error

```
const ENABLE_ALL = gql`
  mutation EnableBox($boxChecked: Boolean!) {
    EnableBox(BoxChecked: $boxChecked) {
      BoxChecked
  }
}
`;

const CheckBoxFunc = () => {
  const [boxChecked, setboxChecked] = useState(false);

  const [enableBox, {data}] = useMutation(ENABLE_ALL, {
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      console.log("could not enable everything", data);
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
      enableBox({
        variables: {boxChecked}
      });
    }
  }, [boxChecked]);

  return (
    <div className="input-group">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="boxChecked"
        name="boxChecked"
        checked={boxChecked}
        onChange={() => setboxChecked(!boxChecked)}
        }
      />
      <label> Enable </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

With this code I am getting,

```
Error: Field "EnableBox" must not have a selection since type "Boolean!" has no subfields.
Cannot query field "BoxChecked" on type "Boolean".
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3):

I've just ended up with this exact issue.

The problem here is the specification of a subsets as return types. Since you are returning a `Boolean` the correct mutation string on client side should be:

```js
const ENABLE_ALL = gql`
  mutation EnableBox($boxChecked: Boolean!) {
    EnableBox(BoxChecked: $boxChecked)
}`;
```

Regards,